# Multiple query for same check gives different result - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server, I have AD users with 'sysadmin' role.

When I execute query

```
 SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('SYSADMIN', 'Domain\agarwals')
```

output is `0`. But when I remove username and execute query

```
 SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('SYSADMIN')
```

output is `1`.

[image]

Has anyone faced this before? Can someone please help me understand why same check from different query gives different output.

Comment: What are you connected as? What does `SELECT SUSER_NAME()` give you?

Comment: Executing SELECT SUSER_NAME() give me my domain ID. Domain\agarwals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

When I execute the query

> SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('SYSADMIN', 'Domain\agarwals')

on my local (am not connected to domain) output is 0 but when I connect to VPN to connect to domain, output is 1.

Whereas output for

> SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('SYSADMIN')

is always 1 no matter my machine is connected to domain or not.

Weird but true.

Answer (score 1):

that is because 'Domain\agarwals' is not part of the sysadmin role.

If no value is specified for the login, the result is based on the current Execution context. So it seems you are a member of sysadmin role and hence the output is 1

Answer (score 0):

On msdn it's mention http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176015.aspx

```
0 login is not a member of role.
1 login is a member of role.
NULL role or login is not valid, or you do not have permission to view the role membership.
```

You can see 0 means agarwals isn't member of sysadmin role.

Comment: Please find the updated image where it shows agarwals is 'sysadmin'